# Hibernate Validation not using Spring Boot LocalValidatorFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, hibernate-validator

I've run into an issue where when `spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode` is set to `auto` (it's default) then it attempts to validate my entities, which is great. However, I have some custom ConstraintValidator's that rely on dependencies being autowired into them via the constructor. As a result I get the error:

```
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000064: Unable to instantiate ConstraintValidator: project.CustomValidator.
```

This is because of:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: project.CustomValidator.<init>()
```

As my dependencies are injected via the constructor there is no 0 arity constructor.

When I create a config for Spring Boot like so:

```kotlin
@Configuration
open class ValidationContext {
    @Bean
    open fun validator(): Validator {
        return LocalValidatorFactoryBean()
    }
}
```

The Spring Boot validator factory works fine, and has no issue instantiating my custom ConstraintValidator. However, Hibernate does not use this factory. Instead it calls out to `Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory()` (see [code](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.4/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/beanvalidation/TypeSafeActivator.java#L502)).

I think I'm meant to do something with either the `SessionFactoryOptions` or `ConfigurationService`, but I have no idea how to configure this in Spring Boot.

How can I get Hibernate to use the LocalValidatorFactoryBean instance?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use the `HibernatePropertiesCustomizer` to specify the validation factory to use. Like so:

```kotlin
@Bean
open fun hibernatePropertiesCustomizer(validator: Validator): HibernatePropertiesCustomizer {
    return HibernatePropertiesCustomizer { properties: MutableMap<String, Any> -> properties["javax.persistence.validation.factory"] = validator }
}
```